# Configuring Ruby with IntelliJ/RubyMine

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, rubygems, rubymine

I am (almost) new to Ruby and try to configure IntelliJ so it helps me developing Jekyll plugins. I am on a Mac and I installed Ruby with RVM. I am willing to move on to Homebrew or whatever.

Jekyll is a static site generator. The plugins for Jekyll should reside inside _plugins which I did.

I added Ruby to the project settings.

The problem now is, IntelliJ tells me I have multiple declarations of in example "require". This happens pretty often, in example for "gem" or "File".

[image]

Some of the dependencies do not seem to be recognized as well.

Here is my Gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'jekyll', '>=3.0.0'
gem 'i18n', '>=0.7.0'
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'pygments.rb'
```

I would have expected that - based on Jekyll dependencies - in example this would have been recognized:

```
Liquid::Template.register_filter( ... )
```

But "Liquid" is not found.

The thing is, the code itself works when I execute it.

But I cannot easily jump into "Array" or the dependency "Jekyll" with clicking on the terms. The "Jekyll" module is even not found, while "Array" is only duplicate.

Here is my classpath for my project:

[image]

For the record, I did "bundle install".

Any ideas what I can do better to make my setup smooth and clean?

Comment: Your _External libraries_ list seems strange. There should gems for your `Gemfile`